# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?

Tags: web3js

**my package.json**

```json
"dependencies": {
   "web3": "^1.2.1"
}
```

**my App.js**

```js
async loadBlockchainData() {
    const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'http://localhost:7545')
    const network = await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
    const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
    const token = new web3.eth.Contract(Token.abi, Token.networks[networkId].address)
    const totalSupply = await token.methods.totalSupply().call()
}
```

but the line with `totalSupply` seems to have some trouble.
This error appears, but I don't know why:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?
>   
> at ABICoder.push../node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-abi/src/index.js.ABICoder.decodeParameters (index.js:227)
>   
> at Contract.push../node_modules/web3/node_modules/web3-eth-contract/src/index.js.Contract._decodeMethodReturn (index.js:418)

It seems like a dependency error, or downgrade another web3 install?
If you know how to solve this problem please let me know...
Thank you...

Comment: I think `totalSupply` function is just reading the smart contract state and not changing it. So I think the error is not correct her.

It would be great if you can share your smart contract code, not the full one but for `totalSupply` method if you created one.

Comment: Did you solve?  I'm doing DappUniversity course, and stuck at same place.

Comment: After switching Metamask to another network and back to Ganache it started working.  At one point, I was also getting "null" returned. Maybe the advanced/reset in Metamask will fix it?

Comment: oh thank you for reply i also solve the problem